# Classic Asp Newsletter suscription problem with Ajax trying to have a loader and confirmation message without refresh the page , Im stuck

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

**STRANGE BEHAVIORS**

No matter how I organize the code:

1. Submit button makes the loader and then the confirmation message appears even if you dont fill the email input form
2. Sometimes refresh the page , sometimes dont

*What I want is simple:*

a) If the email input form is unfilled then dont do nothing just expect the html5 input validation message. 
b) If all is ok and the email input is correctly filled then have the loader appears and then the confirmation message.

I have 3 days in a row, experimenting. I'm STUCK.

Thanks in advance

**AJAX / JS**

```
 function ajaxFunction() {
var form = document.getElementById("contactForm");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('email_suscribe', handleForm);
    
    var ajaxRequest; 
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = ''; // Hide the image after the response from the server
            document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '<img src="images/loading.gif" />'; // Set here the image before sending request
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "includes/suscripcion.asp?email_suscribe=<%=request.form("email_suscribe")%>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**FORM**

`<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm">`

**HTML**

**Email Input Form**

`<input name="email_suscribe" type="email" autocomplete="on" required="required" class="footer_suscribir" placeholder="Correo Electronico" maxlength="60">`

**Submit Button**

`<button name="submit" onclick="ajaxFunction();" class="footer_suscribete"><strong>Suscribete</strong></button>`

**Loader**

`<span id="loading"></span>`

**Real Time Confirmation Message**

`<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>`

Comment: You don't appear to be using `method="post"` in your form tag, which you should if you're using `request.form` in your server side code.  (`method="get"` is the default if you don't specify)

Comment: Remove `onclick="ajaxFunction();"` from the button. Add `onSubmit="ajaxFunction(); return false;"` to the `<form>` tag.

Comment: @John thanks for your answer. Let me clarify something: I already add method="post". In the JS/Ajax Script I'm using GET, because that's the way it is getting the parameters, and, in my server side code I'm using request.querystring because for any reason that server side page is getting the parameters directly from JS code and not from browser querystring. If I change to Request.form, don´t get any info. Strange!

Comment: @Flakes thank you. Changed to OnSubmit , and these are the behaviors: 1) OnSubmit failed dont do nothing. But that way I can´t send empty emails inputs. 2) Onclick the problem is permits empty emails inputs and show the loader. Strange!

Comment: @JohnVaimberg As it is returning false, the form wont be submitted, but the ajax call should work.. You should remove the `function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('email_suscribe', handleForm);` lines, it is defining a function within the `ajaxFunction` and I am not sure what it really is meant to do.

Comment: Also, check the browser console (Press F12), and see if there are any console errors.

Comment: NB, one thing I think you can safely do is simplify it by taking out the browser sniffing code.  You don't have to worry about IE6 and below any more

Comment: By the way, the code is working right now as needed, EXCEPT, I'm unable to stop the form if the email input is empty or not valid, the html5 validation failed and let's the script send empty or wrong email values, but you can see the loader forever looping without any validation alert message. So, the point is that the validation failed onclick and the script failed or do nothing if you change to onsubmit. For the rest is functional. Strange!

Comment: @Flakes function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); }  form.addEventListener('email_suscribe', handleForm); lines, it is defining a function within the ajaxFunction. That's SUPOSSE to avoid the Form natural behavior of refreshing the page. By the way is the same behavior with or without it. I already check the console and the problem is:  with OnClick the server returned a 500 error beuase the parameter ("email")  is empty. OnSubmit if value isempty or wrong the validation halts the process as certainly should. But with values, the page refreshed without do nothing.

Comment: @John NB, "one thing I think you can safely do is simplify it by taking out the browser sniffing code. You don't have to worry about IE6 and below any more.". I don´t understand this. But please read the other comments. The script is functional, the only problem are with the empty values

Comment: What I mean is that you have an if....else conditional statement in your javascript.  You can safely replace all of it with just `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`.  You can forget about IE6 and client side ActiveX objects

Comment: @John is done, code simplified thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this.

HTML

```
<input name="email_suscribe" type="email" autocomplete="on" required="required" class="footer_suscribir" placeholder="Correo Electronico" maxlength="60">
<input type="button" onclick="subscribe()">
<span id="loading"></span>
<span id="ajaxDiv"></span>
```

JS

```
<script>
function subscribe() {
    
    var email=$(".footer_suscribir").val()

    if (isEmail(email)===true) {
        $("#loading").fadeIn("fast")

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "postdata.asp",
        data: {
            "email": email
        },
        success: function (resp) { //resp: return from postdata.asp
            $("#ajaxDiv").html(resp)
            $("#loading").fadeOut("fast")
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $("#ajaxDiv").html("AN ERROR OCCURRED")
            $("#loading").fadeOut("fast")
        }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#ajaxDiv").html("EMAIL FORMAT ERROR")
    }

}

function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
</script>
```

POSTDATA.ASP

```
<%
'...
'DB CONNECTION
'...

' SAMPLE DB EXECUTION

email=request.form("email")

Set rsa=Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
Sorgu="Select TOP 1 email from subscribers WHERE email='"&email&"'"
rsa.Open Sorgu, bag, 1, 3
if rsa.bof then
    rsa.addnew
    rsa("email")=email
    rsa.update
    response.write "SUCCESS"
else
    response.write "ALREADY EXISTS"
end if
rsa.close
set rsa=nothing
%>
```